# Giving Notice - Likely walked out but paid - Can I start elsewhere right away?

Tags: united-states, notice-period

I'm going to be giving my notice at my current employer soon. I know from history that I will most likely be walked out immediately and then paid for the two weeks as if I was working.

If things happen in that order, could I start at my new employer during that two week window?

This is in Pennsylvania, if that matters.

Comment: Is there any reason that you would be ineligible to work a second job even if you weren't leaving? Aside from time constraints?

Comment: Get your second job first, and then get walked out. You will receive an extra paycheck or two which is a windfall.

Answer (score 8):

> If things happen in that order, could I start at my new employer
>   during that two week window?

**Yes**, you can.

Pennsylvania is a *at will* state, meaning that you can leave a company at any time and they can let you go for any reason.

This works in your favor in that you don't have to wait X number of days before starting to work for another company if they ask you to hit the road immediately when you provide your notice.

The only exception to this is *if you sign a contract that states otherwise*, but this is super rare and usually only happens to high ranking company staff such as C level executives.  Another exception could be if you are part of a *union*.

Comment: The only thing that prevents you from leaving right away of course, is eventually a future employer, might talk to one of your past employeers asking for a rererence.  **Leaving before the period of time defined by the employee handbook is a great way to burn a bridge.**  Now if your last day is the same day as when you provide notice, they clearly won't hold it against you, since that escorting you out is clearly the policy.  While you have the right to leave right away, you also might need a reference in the future, and the world is often smaller then one might realize (i.e. networking).

Comment: @Ramhound I don't understand your comment. The OP states that they expect to be walked out the same day they give notice and thus are not expected to work during the two week notice period. How would the OP starting at the new company the next day burn any bridges??

Answer (score 5):

Sure, nothing prevents that.  However... your new employer may have a policy about starting new folks only on the first day of a pay period, or on the first day of the first pay period of a month, etc.  So they may not be ready for you.

Additionally, since you are being paid to not work by your former company, I would recommend some down time between ending and starting the job.  Basically, you've been given a unplanned paid time off vacation.  Take a day or three to do something for yourself, get caught up on projects around your home, etc.

Comment: Or alternatively, use the money to pay off debit and keep working.